# table values as table header

Tags: sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

The query:

```
select Escuser,Eslevel from WF_UserConfiguration
```

is returning me the table bellow:

```
╔═════════════════════╗
║ Escuser     Eslevel ║
╠═════════════════════╣
║ A000        1       ║
║ A010        4       ║
║ A021        3       ║
║ ABCD        1       ║
║ C067        3       ║
║ C099        1       ║
║ C252        2       ║
╚═════════════════════╝
```

My problem is I want to get the following output

```
╔═════════════════════════════╗
║       1     2      3     4  ║
╠═════════════════════════════╣
║     A000  C252   A021  A010 ║
║     ABCD         C067       ║
║     C099                    ║
╚═════════════════════════════╝
```

The table headers `1`, `2`, `3` and `4` are EsLevel values of first query result.

**How should I get the following result (I mean what query)?**

Comment: You can highlight code in your post and click the "code sample" button (with the 0s and 1s) to format your code so that it's readable...

Comment: if you want us to be able to read your prose, check SO editor's help :-)  Hint: type 2 spaces before <enter> to go to new line

Comment: What are the criterias to say the Escusers will belong the same row?

Answer (score 0):

The answer using pivot:
**[See live demo](http://rextester.com/RTMAS78271)**

```
select 
[1],
[2],
[3],
[4] 
from
(
select 
  Escuser,
  Eslevel, 
  Row_number() over(partition by Eslevel order by escuser asc)  as r
from WF_UserConfiguration  
)src
pivot
( 
  max(escuser) 
  for Eslevel in 
   (
    [1],[2],[3],[4]
   )
)p
```